# xml reader limit result

Tags: xml, limit, xmlreader

What is the best way of limiting results when using xml reader?

The code below that I've tried doesn't appear to be working. Instead of just importing 3 nodes, it is still importing the entire file. I've looked at other forums and with credit to rrrfusco and Jose Vega [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349105/php-xmlreader-to-array) here is the code so far:

```
$i = 0;
$limit = 3;

while ($xmlReader->read()) {
if ($xmlReader->name == "product") {
$product = array();

if ($i == $limit) break;

while ($xmlReader->read()) {

$name = $xmlReader->name;

if ($name == "product") break;

  switch($name) {

    case $title:
    case $keywords:
    case $url:

    if (!isset($product[$i][$name]))
    $product[$i][$name] = $xmlReader->readString();


    break;
  }
}
$i++;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my solution, domxpath did the trick. This example will limit the results to 10.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->Load('http://domain.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);




for( $h=1; $h<10; $h++ ) {
$xc = $xpath->evaluate("count(//product[".$h."]/product_name)");
echo "<h1> Hotel" .$h. "</h1>";

$x1 = $xpath->query("//product[".$h."]/product_name");
$title = $x1->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $title."<br /><br />";


    for( $i=1; $i<$xc+1; $i++ ) {

    $x2 = $xpath->query("//product[".$h."]/url[".$i."]");
    $url = $x2->item(0)->nodeValue;


    echo "<li>".$url."</li>";


    }



}
```